# GMaps show static image if Javascript not enabled

Tags: image, google-maps

I am using the Google Maps API which works on Javascript machines, but if they do not have it enabled, nothing is displayed to the user.

Does anyone know of an image URL (similar to Youtube's thumbnail URL) which will create a static image of a map marker? I can't find anything online, but I may be searching the wrong terms.

Thanks

Comment: What about [Google Maps without Scripting](http://googlemapsapi.blogspot.com/2008/02/google-maps-without-scripting.html)?

Comment: I found this after some more searching: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/imageapis/